# Poisson process with bi-directional lines of ants

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Ants form  two single file lines to a bar of chocolate; one towards the chocolate bar, and one towards the nest. However, above the middle of both paths sits a leaky drainage pipe which drops one droplet of water every 3 minutes. When the droplet hits the floor, it cuts both paths simultaneously, blocking the ants movement in both directions for 1 minute. After one minute has passed, it evaporates enough leaving an open path again in both directions. After the droplet has struck the floor, ants heading towards the chocolate bar arrive to the droplet's strike zone at a rate of 10 ants every 30 seconds. In the direction towards the nest, ants arrive at a rate of 6 every 30 seconds.
>
> The arrival of ants in both directions follows a Poisson process. The number of ants to arrive after each drop is independent of the number at the last drop.

***Q.*** What is the probability that after two droplets have struck the ground, a total of 25 ants would have been stopped while heading towards the test?

This is how I'm reasoning the question,

---

We have that $A(t) \sim Po(\lambda = 12)$ where $A(t)$ denotes '*the number of ants stopped in $t$ minutes while heading towards the nest*'.

If we have that a total of 25 ants were stopped after two drops, then we have that 25 ants arrived in 2 different 1 minute intervals.

That means after the first drop we had either:

$0$ or $1$ or $2$ or $3$ or ... or $25$

And hence, after the second drop we had:

$25$ or $24$ or $23$ or ... or $0$

This results in the order pairs $\{\{0,25\}, \{1,24\}, \{2,23\}, ... , \{25,0\}\}$

As a probability (due to independence) this would be,

$$Pr(A(1) = 0)\cdot Pr(A(1) = 25) + $$

$$Pr(A(1) = 1)\cdot Pr(A(1) = 24) + $$

$$Pr(A(1) = 2)\cdot Pr(A(1) = 23) + $$
$$.$$
$$.$$
$$.$$

$$Pr(A(1) = 24)\cdot Pr(A(1) = 1) + $$

$$Pr(A(1) = 25)\cdot Pr(A(1) = 0)$$

However, I feel this is a very long and tedious process, and they only way I can get the answer is through using alpha to compute,

$$\sum_{x = 0}^{25}\frac{e^{-24}(12)^{20}}{x!(20-x)!} \approx 0.062$$

I also feel that I am wrong as well. What's the correct way of doing this? (Or faster way?)

---

EDIT:
It turns out that,

$$\sum_{x = 0}^{25}\frac{e^{-24}(12)^{25}}{x!(25-x)!} = \frac{e^{-24}\big(24^{25}\big)}{25!} = Pr(A(2) = 12)$$

Comment: should it not be $$ \sum^{25}_{x=0} \frac{e^{-24}(12)^{25}}{x!(25-x!)} $$ Also, technically, immediately after the second drop has fallen you have had only one interval of stopping. The second interval of stopping only finishes 1 minute after the second drop.

Comment: Whoops, that it should! I don't suppose there's any other effective means of finding this probability?

Comment: Ah i see, since $\sum^{n}_{x=0}$  ${n}\choose{x}$ $= 2^n$